# scrapy-splash CrawlSpider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I tried to scraping the driver names through scrapy-splash CrawlSpider on this [site](http://www.huananzhi.com/html/1/184/185/index.html), but I constantly come across errors. After searching for ways to solve the problem, I came across [github](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/92) and just copied the latest code.

```
start_urls = ['http://www.huananzhi.com/html/1/184/185/index.html']
def start_requests(self):        
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url,callback=self.parse_item, args={'wait': 0.5}, meta={'real_url': url})

def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
    
    if not isinstance(
            response,
            (HtmlResponse, SplashJsonResponse, SplashTextResponse)):
        return
    seen = set()
    for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
        links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
                 if lnk not in seen]
        if links and rule.process_links:
            links = rule.process_links(links)
        for link in links:
            seen.add(link)
            r = self._build_request(n, link)
            yield rule.process_request(r, response)

def use_splash(self, request, response):
    request.meta.update(splash={
        'args': {
            'wait': 15,
        },
        'endpoint': 'render.html',
    })
    return request
linkRule = LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//article   /div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]')
itemRule = Rule(linkRule, callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_request='use_splash')

rules = (
    itemRule,
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = HuananzhiItem()
    item['name'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='tab-content']//div[1]/h2/text()").get()
    yield item
```

It didn't work so I tried using scrapy.Spider

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'http://www.huananzhi.com/html/1/184/185/index.html'
    
    yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//article/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/@href')
    for link in links:
        yield SplashRequest(url=link, callback=self.parse_item)
    next_page = response.xpath('//section//li[4]//a[1]')
    yield from response.follow(next_page, self.parse)

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = HuananzhiItem()
    item['name'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='tab-content']//div[1]/h2/text()").get()
    yield item
```

i also use [scrapy-user-agent](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-user-agents/)

can anyone tell me how to get the item ? Sorry for such a stupid question, I'm a beginner

Thanks

Comment: To help you should precise what did not work exactly, for instance by giving the error the python's interpreter gave you.